# Control/Monitor Many Windows Command Prompts?

Tags: windows, perl, command-prompt

I need to make running multiple Perl scripts as easy as possible, and make all of their statuses easily known, to see if they are all still working.

I'm thinking of having a single Perl script which runs and monitors the other scripts I have, and displays the data on a 'master' command prompt. Is this possible? Is there an easier way to do this?

Edit: Here's some more info:

I'm doing web scraping and I need to know when batches get done, if a database fails, if the internet is down, etc. I just need to launch 5-6 command prompts so that each one can download pages at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Win32::Proccess::Info to get running process Info/PID, Win32::Process::Kill and System to launch a script.

With those tools you can monitor, create, & stop processes in windows.

If you describe the types of tasks you are working with I'm sure you can get a better answer.